# update a column based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample df

```
city        population          is_identified
Newyork       100000               yes
Buffalo       200000               yes
WashingtonDC  150000
```

How can I remove the values in population if is_identified is `empty or np.Nan`?

The output would like

```
city        population          is_identified
Newyork       100000               yes
Buffalo       200000               yes
WashingtonDC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain 2 conditions - [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with testing empty string and then to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['is_identified'].isna() | df['is_identified'].eq(''), 'population'] = ''
```

Or replace empty string and test misisng value or replace nan and test empty strings:

```
df.loc[df['is_identified'].replace('', np.nan).isna(), 'population'] = ''
df.loc[df['is_identified'].fillna('').eq(''), 'population'] = ''
```

If need processing column `population` by some arithmetic operation later better is set values to `NaN`s:

```
df.loc[df['is_identified'].isna() | df['is_identified'].eq(''), 'population'] = np.nan

#if need integers with missing values
#df['population'] = df['population'].astype('Int64')
```

Comment: I've tried you solution. Instead of making the column value empty whenever there's no `is_identified` value, it is making empty for all other values.

Comment: @aristotle29 - You are right, answer was edited.